# showing undefined data and cannot find my dropdown id

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, charts, drop-down-menu

I have question about the query selector, because I am passing a lot of function for my textboxes that will update different chart when using the dropdown list. I am always getting undefined in my console.log() [Undefined screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPkt7.png) this is my drop down [Dropdown Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rPHJ.png).

```
const selectory = $('#needed').filter(":selected").val();
//const selectory = $("div.chartNine select").val();
function interactiveChart() {
    console.log(selectory)
    console.log(bzvaqxnufhyd1.value)
    if (selectory == 'vdn6') {
    updatingValue = [bzvaqxnufhyd1.value, bzvaqxnufhyd2.value, bzvaqxnufhyd3.value, bzvaqxnufhyd4.value, bzvaqxnufhyd5.value, bzvaqxnufhyd6.value, bzvaqxnufhyd7.value];
    nineChart2.data.datasets[0].data = updatingValue;
    nineChart2.update();
    nineChart2.render(); }
}
```

needed is my id tag for my select under the div chartNine.
and this is my textbox

```
<input type="text3" id="bzvaqxnufhyd1" onchange="interactiveChart()" value="0" />
```

I will be using that function for 7 different charts that is why I need to have that select value so whenever I selected a new drop down, if else will do the magic in my interactiveChart function.
I hope someone can help me or lighten me up regarding my situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I just added multifunction on my textbox which is this one.

```
<input type="text3" id="bzvaqxnufhyd1" onchange="interactiveChart()" value="0" />
```